# PHP: How to know the functions Web Service offers through the WSDL

Tags: php, web-services, soap, sabre

I am currently new to SOAP Web Service. I have gone through a couple of tutorials that describes how to create a SOAP server and Client. [Here is one of them]

However, I have a job to do that involves integration of a Booking of Air Tickets and Reservation of Airline Seats. The Web Service is exposed through a [WSDL] file . I am very confused as to how to start, the functions to call and all that ...

Any help to the right tutorial or explanation will be appreciated.

Comment: have you checked to see if the Soap Service provides a php wrapper? http://www.programmableweb.com/apis/directory/1?apicat=travel

Comment: Thanks i will check and get back.

Comment: The API presented at the link is for integration into their Emulator Platform. The WSDL gives more flexibility such that programmers can connect with their language of choice. I intend to use PHP

Comment: [http://www.sabretravelnetwork.com/home/solutions/products/sabre_web_services](Sabre Web Services)

Comment: Please contact your Sabre Travel Network® representative or Support Team for purchasing a licensed copy of Sabre Emulator API and supporting technical documentation. A license for Sabre Emulator API is available for development use for a 1 time charge of $2,500 USD.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this is a bit too old, but in the DevStudio you have some sample code, and PHP is among the languages provided:
https://developer.sabre.com/resources/sample_code